# Node.js mysql query insert arrays but it gives weird \\"something"\\

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do a query in nodejs which is

I have arrays instructions_0 and instructions_1 and instructions_2 and latlngs_0 and latlngs_1,latlngs_2

```
                var AddPlaceUsed =
                "INSERT INTO most_places_used (instructions_0, instructions_1, instructions_2, place_name, dest_place_name, routePathIndex_0, routePathIndex_1, latitude_0, longitude_0, dest_latitude_0, dest_longitude_0, latlngs_0, latlngs_1, latlngs_2, mintues_between_0, distance_between_0, mintues_between_1, distance_between_1, mintues_between_2, distance_between_2, user_created,created_at) VALUES ?";

            connections.query(AddPlaceUsed, [JSON.stringify(instructions_0),JSON.stringify(instructions_1),JSON.stringify(instructions_2),place_name,dest_place_name,routePathIndex_0,routePathIndex_1,latitude_0, longitude_0, dest_latitude_0, dest_longitude_0, JSON.stringify(latlngs_0), JSON.stringify(latlngs_1), JSON.stringify(latlngs_2), mintues_between_0, distance_between_0, mintues_between_1, distance_between_1, mintues_between_2, distance_between_2, user_created,now_place], function (err, result) {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

Whenever I try to insert them it has an error in MySQL which is

```
 errno: 1064,
   sqlMessage: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''[[{\\"compassDirection\\":\\"west\\",\\"details\\":[{\\"compassDegrees\\":253,\\"endPath' at line 1`,
   sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
```

It gives weird arrays not the ones i'm trying to insert its too much \"\"\ things like i wish someone could know how to help with it

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: var mysql = require("mysql"),
    Connection = require("mysql/lib/Connection.js");

Comment: Remove the `JSON.stringify()`'s around the values in the array.

Comment: If I did its all [object object] I can't even if I parse right no matter what it's same

Comment: I put in MySQL column LongText instead of the JSON and every time I get it I parse it and now everything works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I kept the query the same But I changed in MySQL all of the arrays to Longtext instead of JSON and every time I get the column in NodeJS I use JSON.parse(The value of the column -- array) and everything works so perfect.. Not gonna star as the right answer because its workaround and not the answer but it does the same purpose so anyone needs it here it is <3